# Trying to make image carousel responsive

Tags: jquery, image, carousel

Im beginner with JS. I have a image carousel what worked fine. But when i tried to make it responsive, it won't scroll anymore and responsive thing doesnt work either.

Heres JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var viewport = $( window ).width(); 

    if ( viewport > 1024 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","904");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","834");
    }
    else if ( 769 <= viewport >= 1023 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","765");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","695");
    }
    else if ( 481 <= viewport >= 768 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","348");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","278");
    }
    else ( 320 <= viewport >= 480 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","209");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","139");
    }

    $("#inner_ul li:first").before($("#inner_ul li:last"));

    $("#rightarrow img").click(function(){

        var elemlaius = $("#inner_ul li").outerWidth();
        var vasaktaane = parseInt($("#inner_ul").css("left")) - elemlaius;
        $("#inner_ul:not(:animated)").animate({"left" : vasaktaane},500,function(){    
            $("#inner_ul li:last").after($("#inner_ul li:first")); 
            $("#inner_ul").css({"left" : "-139px"});
        }); 
    });

    $("#leftarrow img").click(function(){

        var elemlaius = $("#inner_ul li").outerWidth();
        var vasaktaane = parseInt($("#inner_ul").css("left")) + elemlaius;
        $("#inner_ul:not(:animated)").animate({"left" : vasaktaane},500,function(){            
        $("#inner_ul li:first").before($("#inner_ul li:last")); 
        $("#inner_ul").css({"left" : "-139px"});
        });   
    });
});
```

Please help me.

My added part:

```
var viewport = $( window ).width(); 

    if ( viewport > 1024 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","904");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","834");
    }
    else if ( 769 <= viewport >= 1023 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","765");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","695");
    }
    else if ( 481 <= viewport >= 768 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","348");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","278");
    }
    else ( 320 <= viewport >= 480 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","209");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","139");
    }
```

It will change element width settings but if i watch it with smaller window, it wont do his job. I use http://quirktools.com/screenfly to watch smaller windows

Comment: Please explain what you changed when you "tried to make it responsive". Your question isn't clear.

Comment: I'm trying to change .imagecarouselwrap and .carouselinner width. One element width is 139px. So if (window).width() is bigger than 1024, it will show 6 slider (6 * 139 = 834px). It need to be changed every time i resize window. If smaller window, less slides.

Comment: Put that in your question, along with some explanation of what code you've modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part should be an else if, not else

```
    else ( 320 <= viewport >= 480 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","209");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","139");
    }
```

```
    else if ( 320 <= viewport >= 480 ) {
        $(".imagecarouselwrap").css("width","209");
        $(".carouselinner").css("width","139");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Slider started working but it doesnt do that other thing...removing slides. Does it change css settings for these classes if i have width added in css.

Comment: It would be hard to know without seeing it really, but no it shouldn't change CSS settings as it's only the width you're changing. You were probably overlapping the images before which is why they didn't "remove". You could try using [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to manually hide images if you need to.

Comment: Jfiddle with code: http://jsfiddle.net/txChW/

It doesnt work there and i dont know why.

Comment: I just added one arrow picture. There could be whatever on that picture.

Comment: You just needed to enable jquery in the sidebar. So that's all working now, can you clear up by what you mean removing slides please? I don't quite understand what you want it to do now? http://jsfiddle.net/txChW/3/

Comment: Changing .carouselinner width removes/adds slides. If i have .carouselinner width 834px it will show 6 slides because 6 * 139 = 834. Others are outside that wrapper and so you just cant see them. So if i calculate 5 * 139 = 695px (only 5 slides are visible). But i need that if i resize window it will change that width and reload carousel. Or just show it already correct if i watch it with...hmm with tablet pc maybe.

Comment: Here is window width 819px: http://api.jquery.com/width/

And if i look it in screenfly, window width is 625px ( http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//api.jquery.com/width/&w=1024&h=600&s=1 ). So it changes.

Comment: That's cool, have a gander at this test page I've created and let me know how you get on. You just need to play about with the widths a bit. Have a look at what I've added, it's mainly the new function declaration (line 78) and how I call it every time the width changes (line 126) :). Best of luck. EDIT: New link for some better code http://pastebin.com/MVZm8mpn

Comment: Oh. SO BIG THANK YOU!!

I thought about that resize thing too.